# How do I properly use a Jackson ObjectMapper to parse JSON received in a play controller?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I work with a Jackson ObjectMapper to generate domain classes like that:

```scala
  /**
   * Allows adding a feature to a collection
   *
   * @param collectionId The ID of the feature collection this feature should be added to
   * @return The JSON representation of the feature persisted (including any data generated during insertion)
   */
  def addFeatureToCollection(collectionId: String) = Action { request =>
    if (geoDataPersistenceService.collectionExistsAndIsPublic(collectionId)) {
      request.body.asJson match {
        case Some(json) => {
          try {
            val f: Feature = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json.toString, classOf[Feature])
            Ok(geoDataPersistenceService.add(f, collectionId))
          } catch {
            case jme: JsonMappingException => BadRequest("Can't map the received JSON to a feature")
          }
        }
        case None => BadRequest("No text body received")
      }
    } else {
      NotFound("No collection by that name")
    }
  }
```

I am aware of the fact that the preferred way in Play would be to use [ScalaJsonCombinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) but in that case I would like to stick with the ObjectMapper since it is a very advanced and well tested implementation.

How can I avoid the useless detour of parsing the JSON received using `request.body.asJson` then serializing it using the `toString` method then parsing it again using the `ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [BodyParsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaBodyParsers). Proper way is implement your own jackson-based BodyParser.